# Discrepancy in Performance between rotation() and linear() Functions in Eigen::Isometry3d

Tags: c++, performance, eigen, transformation, matrix-multiplication

I'm optimizing my C++ code that uses Eigen. I've noticed that when using `Eigen::Isometry3d`, the `rotation()` function is much slower compared to `linear()`. To show this, I wrote a simple program to compute the multiplication between two rotation matrices:

```
Eigen::Transform< double, 3, Eigen::Isometry > a = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();
Eigen::Transform< double, 3, Eigen::Isometry > b = Eigen::Isometry3d::Identity();

for(int i=0; i<1000000; ++i)
{
   auto d = a.rotation()*b.rotation();
}
```

I compiled it using g++ -O0 -o main main.cpp -I/usr/include/eigen3. I used -O0 to avoid optimizations that would remove the loop completely. When executed, it took approximately 15.351 seconds, as measured using the time command in Ubuntu.

However, when I replaced `a.rotation() * b.rotation()` with `a.linear() * b.linear()`, the execution time dramatically decreased to just 0.117 seconds.

According to the Eigen documentation, `Isometry3d` is an alias for `Transform<float, 3, Eigen::Isometry>`, and since the mode is set to Isometry, `rotation()` should essentially be an alias for `linear()`. This implies that using `rotation()` on an Isometry3d should be the same as using `linear()`. However, my tests show otherwise.

I also compiled the code with maximum optimization and inserted random values into the rotation matrix, but `linear()` still outperformed `rotation()` significantly.

I'm using Eigen version 3.3.4 and g++ version 11.4. Can anyone provide a reasonable explanation for this discrepancy?

Comment: IIRC `Isometry::rotation == Isometry::linear` is only true since Eigen 3.4. Also, be careful with using `auto` and Eigen expressions!

Comment: _"I used -O0 to avoid optimizations that would remove the loop completely"_ and also make all timings pointless. Use a benchmarking library like google benchmark instead.

Comment: I upgraded Eigen to the version 3.4 but is the same.  `rotations()`  is much slower

Comment: `rotation` and `linear` results in exactly the same code: https://godbolt.org/z/coq6z7e5a Don't compile without optimizations. Also as noted, assigning to `auto` [does not do what you think it does](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html)

Comment: thanks, I saw that using Eigen 3.4 they results in the same code but using version 3.3.4 it result in a different code. In particular `rotation()` has an extra call to `computeRotationScaling()`. Also, after the @chtz suggestion I tried to update Eigen to the version 3.4 on my laptop but in my case it didn't work maybe is still taking the old version.
In this case `auto` is not really important because I'm not using the results. In general I never use auto for Eigen.